# Cumulative COUNT over a column and reset to 0 if value is zero in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have Pandas series containing negative values and zeros.

```
        VALUES  COUNTER
0    0.000000   0
1   -0.058552   1
2   -0.034268   2
3    0.000000   0
4   -0.007787   1
5   -0.002754   2
6   -0.000353   3
7   -0.004303   4
8   -0.016923   5
9    0.000000   0
```

I would like to create column counter that will start counting strikes of negative values and reset when there will be zero.

Any tips how to effectively do this? I have seen lots of similar questions on cumulative sum using groups, but I cannot find solution for this one.

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe containing your expected output?

Comment: sample dataframe is in the question - i have VALUES and need COUNTER

Comment: `df.groupby(df['VALUES'].eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.groupby(df['VALUES'].eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     VALUES  COUNTER
0  0.000000        0
1 -0.058552        1
2 -0.034268        2
3  0.000000        0
4 -0.007787        1
5 -0.002754        2
6 -0.000353        3
7 -0.004303        4
8 -0.016923        5
9  0.000000        0
```

Comment: Found many complicated examples but this one is brilliant in its simplicity